# Borderless Dialog for an Eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to create a dialog box without borders; that is, no title and no close, minimize, and maximize buttons. Its purpose is to show that a plug-in is waiting for something.

Any suggestions on how to develop a dialog without borders? Or a better way to do it without using dialogs?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by creating a new Shell to keep your dialog contents. Then style  it as desired. For instance, you won't get title bar if you use one of the following constants: `SWT.RESIZE, SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL, SWT.PRIMARY_MODAL, SWT.NO_TRIM`. Example:

```
Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.NO_TRIM);
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
Composite c = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
// add contents
shell.open();
// do something else
shell.close();
```

If you wish to keep you dialog always on top you could use `SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.ON_TOP` combination.

It is also possible to override `setShellStyle(int style)` method in the `Dialog`(if you are using one) and set one of above-mentioned style constants. In this case you would probably need to also override `createButton(Composite parent, int id,
        String label, boolean defaultButton)` method to eliminate buttons (by returning null).